# fortran 77 take string from input until space like input.next() in java

Tags: input, fortran, fortran77

I am a newbie on Fortran 77. I need a code that like input.next() in Java. I want to give an input like "hi how are you today" and check every word one by one, so to do that, i need to take words one by one. What is the simplest way to do it? I can check every character and put characters before space in a character variable but it looks hard way.

Comment: Do you have any code to share? What's not working? What have you tried so far? It's not an "ask for code website".

Comment: *I am a newbie on Fortran 77*  Another questioner tunnelling through from the 1980s !  I urge everyone here not to reveal any advanced technology (Fortran 2003 say, selfie sticks, Zune) which might upset history and the framework of the universe.

Comment: @kazim: FORTRAN77 is about half a century old now. I strongly recommend you to start learning Fortran90 or newer standards of Fortran (2003, or 2008) instead of FORTRAN77. Here is a good starting point "Introduction to Fortran 90: An introduction Course for Novice Programmers (Student Notes), by Rob Davies": https://www.uv.es/dogarcar/man/IntrFortran90.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is probably a duplicate, here is what I have in hand (to show that there is no direct builtin routine, and although it may appear tricky at first sight, it is not that "hard" to write it somehow...) I think there are also more efficient ways based on index() function. If necessary, it may be useful to write a similar routine like "input_next()" to get the next word one-by-one [*].

```
program main
    implicit none
    character(100) line, words( 100 )
    integer n, i

    line = "hi how are you today"   ! input string
    words = ""                      ! words to be obtained

    call split_str( line, words, n )

    do i = 1, n
        print *, "i= ", i, "word= ", trim(words( i ))
    enddo
end

subroutine split_str( line, words, n )
    implicit none
    character(*), intent(in)  :: line
    character(*), intent(out) :: words(*)
    integer,      intent(out) :: n
    integer :: ios
    character(100) :: buf( 100 )  ! large buffer

    n = 0
    do
        n = n + 1
        read( line, *, iostat=ios ) buf( 1 : n )  ! use list-directed input
        if ( ios == 0 ) then
            words( 1 : n ) = buf( 1 : n )   ! if success, copy to the original array
        else
            n = n - 1
            exit       ! if all the words are obtained, finish
        endif
    enddo
end
```

Result:

```
 i=            1 word= hi
 i=            2 word= how
 i=            3 word= are
 i=            4 word= you
 i=            5 word= today
```

---

[*] Here is one possible approach for such `getnextword()`, which obtains a word from an input string (`line`) via list-directed input and remove that word from the string for next call. If no more word is found in `line`, `found` becomes false. (Please search "list-directed input" on the net or in SO pages for more details.)

```
program main
    implicit none
    character(100) line, word
    logical found

    line = "hi how are you today"
    do
        call getnextword( line, word, found )
        if ( .not. found ) exit
        print "(a,a7,2a)", "word= ", trim( word ), " : line= ", trim( line )
    enddo
end program

subroutine getnextword( line, word, found )
    implicit none
    character(*), intent(inout) :: line
    character(*), intent(out)   :: word
    logical,      intent(out)   :: found
    integer :: ios
    character(100) :: buf

    read( line, *, iostat=ios ) buf   ! try to read one word into a buffer via list-directed input

    if ( ios == 0 ) then       ! if success
        found = .true.
        word = trim( buf )      ! save the word
        line = adjustL( line )
        line = line( len_trim( word ) + 1 : )   ! and remove the word from the input line
    else
        found = .false.
        word = ""
    endif
end
```

Result:

```
word=      hi : line=  how are you today
word=     how : line=  are you today
word=     are : line=  you today
word=     you : line=  today
word=   today : line=
```

Comment: This answer pushes SO towards the *gimme the code* site it aspires not to be.  @roygvib has been round long enough to decide whether or not to support that push.

Comment: Apropos my previous comment - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288133/is-using-stack-overflow-for-gimme-codez-questions-encouraged

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thank you very much for the link. My idea is very simple. I believe the current Fortran lacks various functionality of string processing (and basic linear algebra as well) that other scientific-computing oriented languages provide out-of-the-box, and that such primitive functionality is not what the usual user needs to struggle with (it is a waste of time). I'm writing my example to fill the gap for such cases. But this is my own view, and I agree it might be not along the usual purpose of this site (i.e., simple Q and A).

Comment: One more point is that, I usually write such example not for the benefit of OP, but for other people (in future) who might find such Q/A and get some idea about how to do a workaround (in the case where builtins are not provided). I think this kind of "ecosystem" of small code snipets help save the time for users to make similar efforts again and again.

Comment: [Finally, I usually try to see whether the OP has made some efforts or consideration for solving the problem. In the present case, the OP wrote "I can check every character and put characters before space in a character variable but it looks hard way", so I decided to write an easier example. (Btw, this question is almost FAQ , e.g. this page(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/UFGS4c7UGKg) so I believe it needs to be handled by the Standards...)]